# Java control panel not displaying 32 bit Java

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit, windows-10-v20h2

Forgive me if this has been asked before.

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise Edition and I have Java 8 update 25 64 bit installed and Java 8 update 25 32 bit installed but in the Java Control Panel it only shows 64 bit:

[image]

But when I the 32 bit Java I will click OK and Apply

[image]

Then I close Java Control Panel and re-open it and the 32 bit Java disappears and only the 64 bit Java is there.

This is a big pain for me as I run applications that require both 32 bit and 64 bit Java.

I have tried running the Java Control Panel in Admin still same issue.

I can get around this by Launching the application via Firefox and running the .jnlp file in the Java Web Starter file in the 32 bit directory but this is tedious.

I haven't tried uninstalling both Javas and re-trying, I also don't want to just have 32 bit installed as my 64 bit Java applications won't run.

Also I have noticed compared to Windows 7 PC I have the tab Architecture is missing:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am running Windows 10 Enterprise Edition and I have Java 8 update 25 64 bit installed and Java 8 update 25 32 bit installed but in the Java Control Panel it only shows 64 bit:
> Also I have noticed compared to Windows 7 PC I have the tab Architecture is missing:

You are running a version of Java 8 that is seven years old and was originally released in 2014.  The reason the Java Control Panel looks different does not list the architecture is due to the fact, you are running an out-of-date and unsupported version of Java 8. The solution to your problem is to simply update Java 8 to a more recent version.

This will also update the Java Control Panel to a version that supports listing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Java.

Comment: Ahhhh okay. The reason we are running a very old version of Java is because the applications we run in this environment work with this version going higher stops the applications from functioning. The network is a closed network (no internet access). So If I install Java update 162 64 bit version this will show me the "architecture" that I am seeing in the Windows 7 screenshot I provided above.

Comment: 162 isn’t the current version of Java 8

Comment: I know thanks for your answer it helped me. Once I installed 162 the tab appeared.